# Is the sentence "How dare you have shot me?" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I was watching a TV series with a foreign dub and came across the following subtitles:

```
"How dare you have shot me?"
```

Even though I'm not a native English speaker, I'd like to believe that I am relatively proficient in English. That being said, I couldn't help but feel like the sentence sounded extremely weird to me and it made me wonder if it is correct.

Comment: The version in the title differs slightly from the one in the body of the question, although neither sounds correct.

Comment: The version in the *title* of the question is grammatical, although uncommon and strange. (It sounds like phrasing from a hundred years ago.) The version in the *body* of the question is ungrammatical.

Comment: @JasonBassford: No, 100 years ago they might have said "How dare you **to** have shot me" (still awkward), but the title version would still be wrong and, incidentally, barbarous.

Comment: Correct would be "How dare you shoot me?"

Comment: @Robusto My comment was that it sounds *like* something from a hundred years ago, not that it was *exactly* what would have commonly been said back then. But I'd argue that if *how dare you **to** have shot me* was fine back then, then *how dare you have shot me*, while less common, would also have been acceptable. Just as we have many variations on the wording that we use today. (And while I would not use the expression myself today, I certainly do *not* find it obviously wrong or, even less so, "barbarous." It even has a certain rhythm that would be more appropriate in some contexts.)

Comment: I feel like there's a disagreement between tenses here. However, my mother is an English teacher and she can't say for sure, so I'm in no position to state my impression as fact.

Comment: @Jason: I absolutely do not agree that "How dare you have shot me" makes any sense at all, grammatically or otherwise. Nor can I fathom how you might.

Comment: @Robusto So, you're saying you have no clue what the sentence means? You don't understand anything about the situation that's being described? I don't believe that. You surely ***do*** understand what the sentence is talking about. If you can *understand* it, then it makes sense. You even *corrected* it into a different construction that you like more.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Please, no sophistry here. For the record, just because I can dope out some half-formed utterance doesn't mean it's acceptable English, as you ought to know.

Comment: @Robusto There is no sophistry here. I am making an essential distinction between *syntax* and *semantics*. There is also a distinction to be made between things that have *technical validity* and things that are *idiomatic*. In the sentence in dispute, I am claiming that the sentence is *semantically* valid, and that it at least used to be *syntactically* valid. (It might still be.) But what *you* are saying is that it's so unidiomatic in current use that it shouldn't be used. However, what's idiomatic is sometimes a matter of opinion. We simply disagree on its degree of acceptability.

Comment: Uh. No me think that like.

Comment: I realized I used a slightly different question in the body and I have now corrected it. The correct sentence was the one used in the title. I guess we haven't reached a consensus if the sentence is valid or not but I guess we can all agree that the sentence does sound funky!

Answer (score 3):

Taking *dare* to be a modal auxiliary verb, there is nothing wrong with the construction

> How dare you have shot me?

*Dare* gives modal meaning of "have the courage necessary" or "take the risk of", the perfect *have* marks past time, and *shot* denotes the action.

There are several precedents of this usage:

> And **how dare she have failed** under the grinding of the world! (I Never
>   Promised You A Rose Garden, Hannah Green, 1964)
>
> Nick was grateful for the community and put off by the community, and
>   wished with an aggression he had not felt in some time that his wife
>   were here to relieve him of having to make all the decisions. **How dare
>   she have left him alone**. (LET'S GO TO THE VIDEOTAPE; Maazel,
>   Fiona;Harper's Magazine, Vol. 332, Iss. 1993,  (Jun 2016):
>   71-72,74-77.)
>
> If they did say that, **how dare they have said** it (Mr_Tom_Cox, House of Commons (49), asbestos_power_station_hansard_28_july_1983)

Other modal auxiliaries are certainly allowed in similar constructions as the perfect is there to mark the past time of the situation (CaGEL p203):

> He **needn’t / should / might / could have told** her.
>
> We **might / could have been** in Africa.
>
> If he hadn’t lied **she would / might have forgiven** him.
>
> I wish **I could have persuaded** her.

All of the above are declaratives, but could just as well be turned into interrogatives. So, though uncommon, it seems that the grammar would allow *dare* in similar constructions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that `How dare you shoot me` sounds appropriate. It has the correct sentence structure and also sounds right when it is said.

Edit: Spelling error in the `shoot` part. Had written it as `shot` earlier.

Answer (score -1):

Deep down, the verb "dare" wants a noun form of a verb to follow -- usually the "infinitive" form (e.g., "to shoot"), with the gerund form sounding slightly less acceptable (e.g., "He keeps daring going out without a mask").

The perfective "have shot" in the question's example sounds wrong.    I think we get away with eliminating the "to" of the infinitive form because it is such a small change:    "He dared to go out, and she dared go with him."    It feels like the "to" is still implicit in the second clause.

Saying "How dare you to have shot me?" still sounds questionable, especially compared to the simpler "You dared to shoot me?"    Adding tense/aspect to the verb inside the noun phrase feels awkward at best.